# How to change the map center in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

The following code initializes a leaflet map. The initialize function centers the map based on user location. How do I change the center of the map to a new position after calling the initialize function?

```
function initialize() {
map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery Â© <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
}).addTo(map);

map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 8});    
}
```

Answer (score 227, accepted):

For example:

```
map.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923));
```

Comment: `map.flyTo([40.737, -73.923], 8)`  if you want to zoom and animate as well

Comment: In my case however, ```panTo()```, ```flyTo()```, ```setView()``` - all of them take me to the *top left* of the map, and not the center.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi use `setTimeout(function () {map.invalidateSize(true)}, 100);`

Answer (score 160):

You can also use:

```
map.setView(new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923), 8);
```

It just depends on what behavior you want. `map.panTo()` will pan to the location with zoom/pan animation, while `map.setView()` immediately set the new view to the desired location/zoom level.

Comment: I like this one because you also get the zoom level, which is very useful.

Comment: Also you can pass the coordinates as an array: `map.setView([40.737, -73.923], 8)` or an object `map.setView({lat:40.737, lng:-73.923}, 8)`

Comment: panTo was not showing animation, I use `map.setView(latlng, map.getZoom(), { animation: true });`

Comment: animation still not working with `setView`

Answer (score 15):

Use `map.panTo();` does not do anything if the point is in the current view. Use `map.setView()` instead.

I had a polyline and I had to center map to a new point in polyline at every second. Check the code :
GOOD: https://jsfiddle.net/nstudor/xcmdwfjk/

```
mymap.setView(point, 11, { animation: true });
```

BAD: https://jsfiddle.net/nstudor/Lgahv905/

```
mymap.panTo(point);
mymap.setZoom(11);
```

Comment: Doesnt' animate for me.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use:

```
var latLon = L.latLng(40.737, -73.923);
var bounds = latLon.toBounds(500); // 500 = metres
map.panTo(latLon).fitBounds(bounds);
```

This will set the view level to fit the bounds in the map leaflet.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of map-centering problem despite using `panTo()`,`flyTo()` or `setView()` try to adjust the map with [`map.invalidateSize()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    map.invalidateSize(true);
}, 100);
```

jQuery sample:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    mymap.invalidateSize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to change the bounds but without the animation. This worked for me:

```
var bounds = L.latLng(40.737, -73.923).toBounds();
map.fitBounds(bounds, {animation: false});
```

Comment: I have many markers in the map, my use case is to select a marker and zoom it and I want to keep it on the center of the map when zoomend