# How to programmatically click/drag/etc in leaflet with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, leaflet

My leaflet map is currently completely behind a transparent canvas element, so it will never directly register mouse events from a user. As such, I need to programmatically have mouse events register with leaflet.

If I had the quick-intro tutorials code running in my app, AKA:

```
  <div id="backgroundMap"></div>
    <script>
$("#backgroundMap").css("width",$(window).width()).css("height",$(window).height());
        var map = L.map('backgroundMap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/API-Key/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);

        map.on('click', onMapClick);
    </script>
```

would I need mouse events to register in the div backgroundMap, AKA `$('#backgroundMap').click(...)`? Or should it register elsewhere?

Alternatively should I be doing something completely different when it comes to leaflet?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to trigger the click/drag/etc events in Leaflet and whatever listeners to those events? Or do you just want to programmatically move the map around?

If you want the latter, there are a variety of answers at [How to change the map center in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735303/how-to-change-the-map-center-in-leaflet).

This is the command you really want, mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735612/198348):

```
map.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923));
```