# d3 choropleth creates a very small map

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to create a choropleth using d3 for New Jersey state. I have geojson file created as nj.json. You can see it here:

http://mntest.elasticbeanstalk.com/nj.json

When I try to use it to display on web page, it shows a very small New Jersey map, so small it is easy to miss. See it here:

http://mntest.elasticbeanstalk.com/choropleth_test.html

It shows as a small dot a couple of inches below the text.

Can somebody take a look at the source code and guide me how to increase the map size.

Thanks,
D3 newbie

Answer (score 3):

To change the size of the displayed map, set the [scale factor of your projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-scale). You might also want to reset the center of the projection to center what you want to show.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I will try this and let the community know how it goes.

Comment: I tried the first solution in your post, but I am getting this error in javascript console:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'centroid'
My page is at: http://mntest.elasticbeanstalk.com/choropleth_test3.html
This is strange because I can see the method d3.geo.centroid in the file d3.v3.js I am using.
Thanks.

Comment: It says line 26, which is this line:   var center = d3.geo.centroid(json);

Comment: Hmm, try remove the loading of `d3.geo.js` -- you shouldn't need that.

Comment: Thanks. I removed it, now the error is gone but still no map: http://mntest.elasticbeanstalk.com/choropleth_test3.html

Comment: There is no "#vis" element that you could append to.