# D3.Geo performance on Pan/Zoom

Tags: d3.js, gis, topojson

Last year I made a couple experiments on web maps using the [Mapnik library](http://mapnik.org/) (server-side, bitmap/tiling). Now I'm trying to replicate the same experiments using the vector, client-side approach with d3.js.

I have a map (~680 shapes) where `zoom` is slow and `pan` is sluggish ([this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2374239) by Mike Bostock works well). I suspect the problem is in the `zoommove` callback, the `selectAll("path").attr("d", path)` takes too long.

```
function zoommove() {
    projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
    mapa.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
    console.log('zoommove fired...');
}
```

**Questions**:

1. Am I doing something wrong here?
2. what can I do in order to optmize performance?

The map is this ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/scardine/CxTL9/embedded/result/)):

[image: Municipalities from São Paulo State, Brazil]

The datasource is in topojson format. It was simplified, may be already too much, because some shapes are not closing:

[image]

[UPDATE]

Looks like the problem with open geometries occurs even when running topojson without simplification flags, I'm still investigating. I would appreciate any clues here, the documentation is not very detailed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(I'm not super sure what's going on under the hood here, this might be totally wrong).

```
mapa.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
```

Redraws the map from scratch. That works fine for 50 states but starts to get pretty slow with 600+ shapes. You might have better luck if you left the paths in place and just transformed the entire svg:

```
function zoommove() {
  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate("+d3.event.translate+")"
      + " scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
}
```

Which I've used to create a [county level map](http://www.roadtolarissa.com/deportations/) of the US (~500 shapes) that zooms and pans smoothly.

Comment: You got me in the right track. The pan is a bit bumpy because the translate is being calculated over the same element that is moving but I guess I can fix that; edited your answer a bit (`d3.event.translate` is an array), I hope you don't mind.

Comment: The shorter "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" works because of how javascript handles addition of an array and string, but that might be a little too hacky/unclear for the length reduction? Good luck!

Comment: You are right. Edits undone, better post what worked for me in another answer. Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: Also note that I think you need to add a "g" element to group the contents of your map and transform that - applying the transform to the svg object directly does not appear to work.

Comment: when I pan it and if it becomes invisible in the view port since we dragged bit too much then how to drag it back into view port ?  [This example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/eec4a6cda2f573574a11) has such behaviour but I am using above example and not doing selectAll as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here, If you find this helpful, please upvote Adam's answer instead, he deserves the credit.

What worked for me:

```
var bg = svg.append('g')
    .call(zoom);

var map = bg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0) scale(1)");

...

function zoommove() {
    var t1 = projection.translate(),
        t2 = d3.event.translate,
        t = [t2[0]-t1[0], t2[1]-t1[1]];

    map.attr("transform", 
        "translate("+t+") " +
        "scale("+(d3.event.scale/s)+")"
    );
    console.log(map.attr("transform"));
}
```

Some tips:

- if `projection.translate()` is not [0, 0], you have to take it in account, otherwise a big bump will occur on the first time you try to pan/zoom (only the first time).
- if `projection.scale()` is not 1, you have to take it in account.
- the `.call(zoom)` must be in the maps parent element, otherwise panning/zooming becomes bumpy.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across similar issues, and a rescaling was not suitable for my solution as i did not want the svg elements themselves to be scaled.  What I did instead was optimize it such that elements out of the visible area were not recalculated.  This means that when all the elements are in the view performance is still bad, but when you zoom in it's much better.

ode sample:

```
clippedArea.selectAll("circle")
    .style("visibility", d => pointInDomain(d, domain) ? "visible" : "hidden")
    .filter(d => pointInDomain(d, domain))
  .attr("cx", d => xz(d.x));
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simonbleier/62ufqbbq/)

Comment: did you ever apply this clipping mechanism to a map?