# Centering d3.js Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, geojson

I attempted to follow Jan van Der Laan's solution for centering a geoJSON object found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654988/2423246. However, it neither properly scales nor centers my object. I have played around with some of the numbers to manually center it, as can be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/jcahan/459ec19aa516ba722651.

However, the scale is still not working properly. I would very much appreciate any recommendations for how to properly center it, given that the chosen answer for d3.js has unfortunately not been working for me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried any of the other answers?

Comment: Yes, I tried Paulo's (http://bl.ocks.org/jcahan/3acc0bdffa28dd67e758), and I originally had tried mbostock's but I was confused abouthow he defined the variable "state," when I looked here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858. While he uses topojson, I am using geoJSON

Comment: That example is using topojson -- `state` is simply the object you want to center.

Comment: hi @LarsKotthoff, specifically these two lines confuse me:  var states = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states),
      state = states.features.filter(function(d) { return d.id === 34; })[0];. I am not quite sure what the equivalent of .states is for my dataset. I have looked for topojson tutorial that help identify what the equivalent value is, but could not find any. 

I believe mine should look something like this (but slightly off): 
var boroughs = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.features),
    borough = boroughs.features.filter(function(d) { return d.id === 5; })[0];

Comment: Only if you're using topojson. Otherwise it will be something like `var boroughs = data.features`.

Comment: I have attempted to implement your solution without using topojson here: http://bl.ocks.org/jcahan/e66f06e9e8be46ef05c9. However, I run into an issue with parsing now. Following your recommendation, I defined the variable boroughs to equal data.features, and the variable borough to equal boroughs.filter(function(d) { return d.BoroCode === 5; })[0];. I am unsure of the second line still, but I am working with 5 boroughs each of which has its own BoroCode in the geoJSON.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33228/discussion-between-jsc123-and-lars-kotthoff)