# Draw a map with D3.js: How to get the right scale() and translate()?

Tags: d3.js, geocoding

I want to draw a map of german districts. My code follows the youtube-tutorial of d3vienno http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJgEx_yb4u0.

When I open the page, it is blank. When I inspect the code, the svg and g elements are there. I already know that I have to adjust scale() and translate().

So I tried different values and read posts here on stackoverflow that a dealing with the topic.

Nevertheless, nothing worked. Can you help?

This is the site: http://test.schafott.net/hogn/bayern.html

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 700)
.attr("height", 700)

d3.json("data/gemeinden_bayern.geojson", function(data) {


var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
    .data(data.features)  
    .enter()
    .append("g")

var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(7300).translate([0, 1980]); 

//path generator
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection); 

//append to path to each "g" element
var areas = group.append("path")
    .attr("d", path) //data comes from path generator
    .attr("class", "area") //CSS
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object)?

Comment: No, I haven't. Thanks! It is really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6791875) based on your example, it's not been centred using the code as in the question Lars has pointed to.  Btw you should definitely read that question and answer.

Comment: oh, that's cool! Thanks a lot. So the curcial thing is to include center()? If yes, where do I get the coordinates for it? just choose something from my dataset? I appreciate :)