# zoom map based on selected value on the drop down list

Tags: javascript, d3.js, queue

Good day,

I am having trouble with the D3 map that i created. i want to zoom the world map not by clicking on the country but selecting on the drop down list of countries inside the drop down control.

here is my code..

```
        var dispatch = d3.dispatch("load", "countrychange");
         d3.csv("data/ERSreputationBlocked.csv",type, function (error, country) {
      if (error) throw error;
      var countryById = d3.map();
      country.forEach(function (d) { countryById.set(d.id, d); });
      dispatch.load(countryById);
      dispatch.countrychange(countryById.get("PH"));
      //console.log(country);
  });
  dispatch.on("load.menu", function(countryById) {
      var select = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .append("select")
        .on("change", function () {                       dispatch.countrychange(countryById.get(this.value)); });

      select.selectAll("option")
        .data(countryById.values())
        .enter().append("option")
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.id; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.Country; });

      dispatch.on("countrychange.menu", function (country) {
          select.property("value", country)
          //loading the value based on the selected data
          var svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg1")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
          //end of selection

         console.log(country);
      });
  });
  //end of drop down

  function type(d) {
      d.total = d3.sum(d.value, function (k) { return d[k] = +d[k]; });
      return d;
  }
```

is there a way on how to manipulate this...

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/)?

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff yes, just like that .when i debug my code using using safari browser i can see the id and country name of the selected value in drop down

Comment: So you should just need to adjust the projection for that. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) should help.