# D3.js -- Equirectangular Projection Sizing Woes

Tags: d3.js, projection

all.

I'm working on a project that involves overlaying a map of the state of Kansas (that includes county borders, and some other geographic details) on top of a **static, equirectangular base map** that I've designed in Adobe Illustrator.

I'm having no problems *generating* the equirectangular projection. But when it comes to sizing the projection so that it fits **exactly** on top of the static base map, I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm guessing the secret lies within these functions.

```
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
    .scale(1)
    .translate([0, 0]);
```

If the total size of my static base map image is, say, **1000px by 300px**, and the outline of Kentucky in which the projection must fit is **530px by 230px**, how can I tweak the scale/transform and other functions to resize the projection?

Here is a link to a proof-of-concept illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEtR1.png

The background image is obviously fixed in width/height. The transparent outline of Kansas that's overlaid would be generated by D3, but would have to be tweaked to fit the map.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) tells you how to translate/scale a map to fit a particular feature. You would have to do the same for Kansas, maybe tweaking a little bit to get it exactly right.