# D3 - where do I add d3.behavior.zoom() to a rescaled map

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, zooming

The answer at [Center a map in d3 given a geoJSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) helped me to determine better values for scale and translation of a map of Toronto. My script is available on http://www.climateactionnow.ca/map-script

Now I would like to add zoom behavior following the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2374239

However, I am not sure where to add the zoom code due to the redrawn projection. Can anyone suggest how to place the zoom code?

Comment: Instead of modifying the projection, you would modify the transform of the SVG. The values for that (translate, scale) can be determined the same way.

Comment: i am not sure "where to add the zoom due to the redrawn project"  if you mean which element to add event listener, it is simple to  add  event listener to root svg, because zoom event will bubble up to it,  if you want to get scale and translate information, you can  visit d3.event for imformation. here is a good example :http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/2322933

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear about the process. I have a group that includes the map (after it has been rescaled,) and with an overlay of circles with actions attached to them (sorry I know I am not using the correct terms.) I do not want to use scrolling for zooming. I would prefer to use click/double click but I have click defined as one of the actions for the circles. Can I do both? i.e. if I click on the map outside of the circles it will zoom?

Comment: The correct behaviour was obtained following the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct behaviour was obtained following the example at bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590