# Plotting points on a map with D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geo

I'm trying to plot a few points onto a map using the D3 geo library based on latitudes and longitudes. However, when I pass these values into my projection function, it results in coordinates that our outside the bounds of my SVG image. My code is based on [this example provided in the documentation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3757119).

I've thrown the current code up at: http://bl.ocks.org/rpowelll/8312317

My source data is a simple array of objects formatted like so

```
var places = [
  {
    name: "Wollongong, Australia",
    location: {
      latitude: -34.42507,
      longitude: 150.89315
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Newcastle, Australia",
    location: {
      latitude: -32.92669,
      longitude: 151.77892
    }
  }
]
```

Following this I set up an Plate Carrée projection like so:

```
var width = 960,
height = 480

var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
    .scale(153)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
```

From there I draw the map with code effectively identical to the linked example. At the end of my script, I use the following code to plot points on this map:

```
svg.selectAll(".pin")
    .data(places)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + projection([
        d.location.latitude,
        d.location.longitude
      ]) + ")"
    })
```

However this code results in points that are outside of the SVG element's bounds. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like the scale/translate of your projection is off. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) may help.

Comment: It seems like the projection itself is alright, as the actual map path uses the same projection and draws without issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your code -- coordinates should be passed as (longitude, latitude) to the projection, not the other way round. This code should work fine:

```
 svg.selectAll(".pin")
  .data(places)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection([
      d.location.longitude,
      d.location.latitude
    ]) + ")";
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems somewhat counterintuitive though.

Comment: @rpowell It is counterintuitive because we *say* "latitude and longitude", but we say them backwards -- longitude is the x-coordinate and latitude is the y-coordinate, and the translation expects its arguments in the order x, y.