# How can we draw D3 map of city and render a line connected with nodes over it?

Tags: javascript, svg, dictionary, d3.js, openstreetmap

I'm at present trying to draw a d3 map graph i.e as [here](http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-world-map-click-into-usa.html) and over the graph i want to highlight few places whose latitude and longitude i posses connected via points as this grap [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) , I'm not getting how to create relation between svg and lat long data.

And also is using open street maps with d3 a good choice to render data points maps ?

please let me know how can i achieve it.

Comment: If you know the position of the points, what do you want to use a force directed layout for?

Comment: i do not want to use a force layout graph but just need to represent points connected through lines on the map

Comment: There are lots of questions and examples for this, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987535/plotting-points-on-a-map-with-d3).