# Displaying circle on a specific Latitude and Longitude in d3 map

Tags: javascript, svg, dictionary, d3.js

I am using a **.svg** file for plotting India map. It is displaying India map as desired.
Now I want to display circles on this map using latitude and longitude.

How can I draw circles by using **places** array? Any source code and web link would be appreciated.

My index.html code is as like below and the svg file I am using is [here](http://questoons.com/vkwave/d3-india-map/toilet.svg).
The final output of my script is [here](http://questoons.com/vkwave/d3-india-map/).

** **Please also guide me, is this the correct way of displaying map?**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var places = [
              {
                name: "GUNA",
                location: {
                  latitude: 24.5429,
                  longitude: 77.1032
                }
              },
              {
                name: "THE DANGS",
                location: {
                  latitude: 20.4633,
                  longitude: 73.4646
                }
              }
            ]

            d3.xml("toilet.svg", function(xml) {
                var x = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
                document.body.appendChild(x)
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987535/plotting-points-on-a-map-with-d3) should help.

Comment: Thanks for replying LarsKotthoff sir. I could not solve this puzzle by following your hint so I did it by using json format. 
BTW... I am your big fan @LarsKotthoff

Comment: This may also help: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/