# d3.geo.Transformation With non-geoJSON data

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to create a map based D3 visualisation but my limitation is that my data is a tabular, csv format data. I have two options - 
1. Convert the csv to a geoJSON format in javascript itself
2. Work with the csv data and figure out how to get the D3 functions to work with it.

I'm trying to modify this example - http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/ to work with my data which has two columns with latitude and longitude data but I'm unable to get the transform and projection working.

Any advice?

Data:

```
Value1,Value2,Lat,Long
1,2,15,16
4,2,15.01,16.03
4,2,15.03,16.02
```

Part where I think I'm stuck at:

I've modified some of the code: pointing it to a csv, setting the map to center around my data, Using `d.lat` and `d.long` instead of `d.geometry.coordinates` wherever visible. I'm unable to test it as `d3path.bounds` gets set to +- infinities and no overlay svg is created. My feeling is that the `projectPoint` function 1which takes `(x,y)` needs some modifications but I'm unable to figure out how x and y are getting mapped to the coordinates.

Comment: What does your data look like? How are you unable to get it working?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I've added these details to the question.

Comment: So like in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/sumbera/10463358)?

Comment: Possibly. It looks like a really busy example so let me go through it with some patience :).

Comment: Isn't this example basically taking a CSV and converting it to a geoJSON? I have a fairly large dataset (a few MB, a few thousand rows) and I'm worried that there will be significant cost if I try to do that. Is there no way to work off of a csv itself?

Comment: Okay, I amped up the data to about 270,000 rows and it was still almost instantaneous. Can I safely assume that performance won't be an issue then or are there any caveats?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. The bottleneck is usually the rendering.

Comment: Thanks, @LarsKotthoff. If you can post this as an answer, I can close the question.

Comment: Well this isn't really an answer :) Would you say that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987535/plotting-points-on-a-map-with-d3) is similar enough to yours to mark this one as a duplicate?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question of using a csv directly. If not for that, this questions basically breaks down into a convert CSV to geoJSON sort of a question. If there is a way of getting the CSV to work directly, I'd still be happier since I have other code that uses the csv format already. For now, I'm accepting that there is no performance issue on converting CSV to geoJSON and I now need to restructure the rest of my code to work with that.