# How does d3 projection scales work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, map-projections

I have a simple question: What does it mean to set the scale of a d3 projection to 1 compared to, say, 150? What do these values actually translate to in plain English? I understand that it scales the projection up and down (duh), but according to what principle?

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(1) //what does this mean?
```

Comment: does the following question not answer your's? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565511/what-does-it-mean-to-scale-a-projection-in-d3

Comment: @hubsonbropa I guess I'm looking for a more specific answer than "scale is used in the general sense of the size of something". If there is one.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#scale)? The scale factor affects the distance between projected points.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yeah. But what does that mean? With scale set to 1, one meter equals one pixel, and with scale 150, one meter equals 150 pixels, or what?

Comment: @durrrutti What it means exactly depends on the projection you're using. What a scale of 1 corresponds to varies by projection, but a scale of 150 will put the same points 150 times as far apart for the same projection.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Ok. I used the mercator projection with Natural Earth data and set the scale to 1. The bounding box for the whole world ended up being [`[-3.14, -2.88], [3.14, 3.14]]`. I guess I'm bothered by the fact that I have no idea how these starting values were computed.

Comment: @durrrutti You can always have a look at the source :)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Too much math :) But perhaps the answer is that there's no trivial, non-mathematical, answer to the question.

Comment: @durrrutti Exactly -- it really depends on what the projection does under the hood and there's no intrinsic meaning of a "1" here.