# Why is scale a function of pi in D3's Mercator projection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, map-projections

In every D3 map example I can find, the `scale` parameter of the Mercator projection is set to equal   `width / 2 / Math.PI`. Is this unique to the Mercator projection? What is `scale` doing that it needs to rely on pi? I'd love to have a more intuitive understanding of what's going on here, but the docs are pretty sparse.

> "If scale is specified, sets the projection’s scale factor to the specified value and returns the projection. If scale is not specified, returns the current scale factor which defaults to 150. The scale factor corresponds linearly to the distance between projected points. However, scale factors are not consistent across projections."

Comment: Not sure what examples you're referring to. There's certainly no need for it to be specified in terms of pi.

Comment: Here's one: http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-worldmap-boilerplate.html

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) shows how to fit a given object within the container and doesn't rely on pi to compute the scale.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mercator projection code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/2c93d9c1924461708876781cdc96f139b205c33d/src/geo/mercator.js) uses a lot of trig to convert between angular lat/long coordinates and cartesian x/y coordinates.  I'm pretty sure that the `width/2/Math.PI` just makes sure that the entire globe fits within a `width`.  (Within the code, your input scale factor gets multiplied by pi.)  If you're not mapping the entire globe, you'll need to figure out an appropriate scale factor yourself.