# D3 - Large GeoJSON File does not show draw map properly using projections

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, data-visualization, geojson

I am having an issue with drawing this GeoJSON file I picked up from data.seattle.gov. Specifically, I'm using the Shape file which can be found [here](https://data.seattle.gov/Crime/Seattle-Police-Department-Beats/nnxn-434b). I converted it to a GeoJSON file where I provided a small sample below.

By using D3, I was hoping to draw out what should be the different precincts in Seattle (actually I'm not entirely sure what it should be which is why I'm drawing it... ha...) but for some reason it isn't showing it correctly despite the fact that the paths are correctly calculated.

I have hosted my example [here](http://students.washington.edu/augbog/datascience/index.html). I will try to replace this link with a jsFiddle when I have time to set it up. The thing is, the GeoJSON file is pretty big so I don't think jsFiddle would be ideal.

My code is pretty simple... I'm just appending paths based on the features of the GeoJSON file.

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 1000;

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + "px")
            .attr("height", height + "px");

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(150)
    .translate([width/2, height/2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

d3.json("geojson/data.geo.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", "5px")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0);
});
```

Unfortunately, I feel it's only showing one of the paths and not all of them. At first I thought it might be because there was a fill of some sort and they were simply hiding on top of each other, but I set the `fill-opacity` to 0 and that didn't help either.

Here is a small sample of the GeoJSON file.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -122.349453,
                            47.717771
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.34948,
                            47.719585
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.349504,
                            47.721403
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.350214,
                            47.721404
                        ],
                        ...
                        [
                            -122.350337,
                            47.721405
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.350258,
                            47.71596
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.349425,
                            47.715958
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.349453,
                            47.717771
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "B1",
            "styleUrl": "#PolyStyle00",
            "styleHash": "-59c62042",
            "description": "<html xmlns:fo=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format\" xmlns:msxsl=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt\">\n\n<head>\n\n<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html\">\n\n</head>\n\n<body style=\"margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;\">\n\n<table style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px\">\n\n<tr style=\"text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2\">\n\n<td>B1</td>\n\n</tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>\n\n<table style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px\">\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>FID</td>\n\n<td>0</td>\n\n</tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>BEAT</td>\n\n<td>B1</td>\n\n</tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>PRECINCT</td>\n\n<td>N</td>\n\n</tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>Shape_Leng</td>\n\n<td>53375.265498</td>\n\n</tr>\n\n</table>\n\n</td>\n\n</tr>\n\n</table>\n\n</body>\n\n</html>\n\n"
        }
    },
    ...
```

What ends up being drawn is something is this...

[image: D3 Drawing of GeoJSON File...]

Any help would be most appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry it seems my student account from way back when is gone. I can try to recreate the example later.

Comment: You need to set zoom and translation appropriately, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for the link. I tried messing around with centering my projection but I still end up with a blank svg with the bounding box. In Mike's example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858) he references a single state to center on by filtering the other states out. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to specify centering in on the collection of all the Polygons in my GeoJSON file :/ Any idea how to fix that? And thanks for responding!

Comment: The first answer for the question I've linked to centers on the whole file.

Comment: I tried using the code but it still didn't work out. It ends up simply drawing out the outline of the svg and also the outline of the GeoJSON file without any of the beat zones showing :/ I reproduced it [here](http://students.washington.edu/augbog/datascience/index.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a look at your problem. The problem seems to be with the map. I ran into the same problems as you have, although I had no issue creating a map from the older (pre 2008) files on the site you linked to. [Mapshaper](http://www.mapshaper.org) (mapshaper.org) had no problem plotting both graphs, so the problem seems to be with d3 and this specific map. I have no time to look into the reason for this.

Simplifying the map using mapshaper (which is something you might want to do anyway) seems to result in a map that can be correctly drawn:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON map_tmp.json spd_beats_wgs84.kmz
mapshaper -p 0.5 --repair -o map.json map_tmp.json
```

I can then draw the map using the following code:

```
var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

d3.json("map.json", function(map) {
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1).translate([0,0]).precision(0);
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
  var bounds = path.bounds(map);

  var scale = .95 / Math.max((bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]) / width,
      (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]) / height);
  var transl = [(width - scale * (bounds[1][0] + bounds[0][0])) / 2,
      (height - scale * (bounds[1][1] + bounds[0][1])) / 2];
  projection.scale(scale).translate(transl);

  vis.selectAll("path").data(map.features).enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black");
});
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I ended up using R to draw the map as an SVG, saved it as an SVG file, and uploaded to a webpage to solve my immediate issues for those wondering but this is definitely the answer I was looking for. I'll definitely take a look into Mapshaper. Needless to say thank you so much.

If you have time, I'd really appreciate knowing what was wrong with the map because I think that'd be the most beneficial for viewers. I'll also look into it and update your answer if I find anything.

Comment: bounds is a 2x2 array. How do you have indices [0][3], [1][4] and [0][5]?

You want:
```
        var scale = 0.95 / Math.max((bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]) / width,
            (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]) / height);
        var transl = [(width - scale * (bounds[1][0] + bounds[0][0])) / 2,
            (height - scale * (bounds[1][1] + bounds[0][1])) / 2];
```

Comment: @AshwinBalamohan: you are right. Weird. I have corrected this. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan thanks for the solution. It was helpful. I see that you've updated the transl variable assignment, but the the scale variable still has array indices greater than 1.

Comment: @AshwinBalamohan that has now also been fixed.

Comment: This d3 issue with large files drove me nuts! At start, it seemed so puzzling when on one hand there was no code errors reporting during rendering and small files seemed to work, and on the other, this large block was getting shown!! I even re-created topo files from shape files. But it didn't work. And to add to the confusion, it worked on mapShaper!!!

Comment: Yeah, so simplifying paths for some reason makes file render map successfully with d3