# Best projection in d3 to display any map

Tags: json, d3.js, projection

Am trying to create a `d3` map using geo json using albers projection as follows:

```
         var projection =  d3.geo.albers()
        .scale(1)
        .translate([0, 0]);

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        var b = path.bounds(features),
        s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
        t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

        projection.scale(s).translate(t);
```

The above code scales and translates my map correctly. How ever if I try to draw Australia alone using above code, map is being drawn vertically. Is there a way to center and properly rotate map ( without trail and error). Is there a way to use albers projection for any geo json.

If not , any pointers as to which is the best projection to use for any geo json so that i will be able to draw any map with the given code.

My geo json looks like this:

```
{       "type": "FeatureCollection",        "features": [
                { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "income_grp": "1. High income: OECD", "pop_est": 21262641.000000, "mapcolor7": 1.000000, "continent": "Oceania", "economy": "2. Developed region: nonG7", "mapcolor13": 7.000000, "iso_a3": "AUS", "name": "Australia", "mapcolor9": 2.000000 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 145.397978, -40.792549 ], [ 146.364121,
-41.137695 ], [ 146.908584, -41.000546 ], [ 147.689259, -40.808258 ], [ 148.289068, -40.875438 ], [ 148.359865, -42.062445 ], [ 148.017301,
-42.407024 ], [ 147.914052, -43.211522 ], [ 147.564564, -42.937689 ], [ 146.870343, -43.634597 ], [ 146.663327, -43.580854 ], [ 146.048378,
-43.549745 ], [ 145.431930, -42.693776 ], [ 145.295090, -42.033610 ], [ 144.718071, -41.162552 ], [ 144.743755, -40.703975 ], [ 145.397978,
-40.792549 ] ] ], [ [ [ 143.561811, -13.763656 ], [ 143.922099, -14.548311 ], [ 144.563714, -14.171176 ], [ 144.894908, -14.594458 ], [ 145.374724, -14.984976 ], [ 145.271991, -15.428205 ], [ 145.485260,
-16.285672 ], [ 145.637033, -16.784918 ], [ 145.888904, -16.906926 ], [ 146.160309, -17.761655 ], [ 146.063674, -18.280073 ], [ 146.387478,
-18.958274 ], [ 147.471082, -19.480723 ], [ 148.177602, -19.955939 ], [ 148.848414, -20.391210 ], [ 148.717465, -20.633469 ], [ 149.289420,
-21.260511 ], [ 149.678337, -22.342512 ], [ 150.077382, -22.122784 ], [ 150.482939, -22.556142 ], [ 150.727265, -22.402405 ], [ 150.899554,
-23.462237 ], [ 151.609175, -24.076256 ], [ 152.073540, -24.457887 ], [ 152.855197, -25.267501 ], [ 153.136162, -26.071173 ], [ 153.161949,
-26.641319 ], [ 153.092909, -27.260300 ], [ 153.569469, -28.110067 ], [ 153.512108, -28.995077 ], [ 153.339095, -29.458202 ], [ 153.069241,
-30.350240 ], [ 153.089602, -30.923642 ], [ 152.891578, -31.640446 ], [ 152.450002, -32.550003 ], [ 151.709117, -33.041342 ], [ 151.343972,
-33.816023 ], [ 151.010555, -34.310360 ], [ 150.714139, -35.173460 ], [ 150.328220, -35.671879 ], [ 150.075212, -36.420206 ], [ 149.946124,
-37.109052 ], [ 149.997284, -37.425261 ], [ 149.423882, -37.772681 ], [ 148.304622, -37.809061 ], [ 147.381733, -38.219217 ], [ 146.922123,
-38.606532 ], [ 146.317922, -39.035757 ], [ 145.489652, -38.593768 ], [ 144.876976, -38.417448 ], [ 145.032212, -37.896188 ], [ 144.485682,
-38.085324 ], [ 143.609974, -38.809465 ], [ 142.745427, -38.538268 ], [ 142.178330, -38.380034 ], [ 141.606582, -38.308514 ], [ 140.638579,
-38.019333 ], [ 139.992158, -37.402936 ], [ 139.806588, -36.643603 ], [ 139.574148, -36.138362 ], [ 139.082808, -35.732754 ], [ 138.120748,
-35.612296 ], [ 138.449462, -35.127261 ], [ 138.207564, -34.384723 ], [ 137.719170, -35.076825 ], [ 136.829406, -35.260535 ], [ 137.352371,
-34.707339 ], [ 137.503886, -34.130268 ], [ 137.890116, -33.640479 ], [ 137.810328, -32.900007 ], [ 136.996837, -33.752771 ], [ 136.372069,
-34.094766 ], [ 135.989043, -34.890118 ], [ 135.208213, -34.478670 ], [ 135.239218, -33.947953 ], [ 134.613417, -33.222778 ], [ 134.085904,
-32.848072 ], [ 134.273903, -32.617234 ], [ 132.990777, -32.011224 ], [ 132.288081, -31.982647 ], [ 131.326331, -31.495803 ], [ 129.535794,
-31.590423 ], [ 128.240938, -31.948489 ], [ 127.102867, -32.282267 ], [ 126.148714, -32.215966 ], [ 125.088623, -32.728751 ], [ 124.221648,
-32.959487 ], [ 124.028947, -33.483847 ], [ 123.659667, -33.890179 ], [ 122.811036, -33.914467 ], [ 122.183064, -34.003402 ], [ 121.299191,
-33.821036 ], [ 120.580268, -33.930177 ], [ 119.893695, -33.976065 ], [ 119.298899, -34.509366 ], [ 119.007341, -34.464149 ], [ 118.505718,
-34.746819 ], [ 118.024972, -35.064733 ], [ 117.295507, -35.025459 ], [ 116.625109, -35.025097 ], [ 115.564347, -34.386428 ], [ 115.026809,
-34.196517 ], [ 115.048616, -33.623425 ], [ 115.545123, -33.487258 ], [ 115.714674, -33.259572 ], [ 115.679379, -32.900369 ], [ 115.801645,
-32.205062 ], [ 115.689611, -31.612437 ], [ 115.160909, -30.601594 ], [ 114.997043, -30.030725 ], [ 115.040038, -29.461095 ], [ 114.641974,
-28.810231 ], [ 114.616498, -28.516399 ], [ 114.173579, -28.118077 ], [ 114.048884, -27.334765 ], [ 113.477498, -26.543134 ], [ 113.338953,
-26.116545 ], [ 113.778358, -26.549025 ], [ 113.440962, -25.621278 ], [ 113.936901, -25.911235 ], [ 114.232852, -26.298446 ], [ 114.216161,
-25.786281 ], [ 113.721255, -24.998939 ], [ 113.625344, -24.683971 ], [ 113.393523, -24.384764 ], [ 113.502044, -23.806350 ], [ 113.706993,
-23.560215 ], [ 113.843418, -23.059987 ], [ 113.736552, -22.475475 ], [ 114.149756, -21.755881 ], [ 114.225307, -22.517488 ], [ 114.647762,
-21.829520 ], [ 115.460167, -21.495173 ], [ 115.947373, -21.068688 ], [ 116.711615, -20.701682 ], [ 117.166316, -20.623599 ], [ 117.441545,
-20.746899 ], [ 118.229559, -20.374208 ], [ 118.836085, -20.263311 ], [ 118.987807, -20.044203 ], [ 119.252494, -19.952942 ], [ 119.805225,
-19.976506 ], [ 120.856220, -19.683708 ], [ 121.399856, -19.239756 ], [ 121.655138, -18.705318 ], [ 122.241665, -18.197649 ], [ 122.286624,
-17.798603 ], [ 122.312772, -17.254967 ], [ 123.012574, -16.405200 ], [ 123.433789, -17.268558 ], [ 123.859345, -17.069035 ], [ 123.503242,
-16.596506 ], [ 123.817073, -16.111316 ], [ 124.258287, -16.327944 ], [ 124.379726, -15.567060 ], [ 124.926153, -15.075100 ], [ 125.167275,
-14.680396 ], [ 125.670087, -14.510070 ], [ 125.685796, -14.230656 ], [ 126.125149, -14.347341 ], [ 126.142823, -14.095987 ], [ 126.582589,
-13.952791 ], [ 127.065867, -13.817968 ], [ 127.804633, -14.276906 ], [ 128.359690, -14.869170 ], [ 128.985543, -14.875991 ], [ 129.621473,
-14.969784 ], [ 129.409600, -14.420670 ], [ 129.888641, -13.618703 ], [ 130.339466, -13.357376 ], [ 130.183506, -13.107520 ], [ 130.617795,
-12.536392 ], [ 131.223495, -12.183649 ], [ 131.735091, -12.302453 ], [ 132.575298, -12.114041 ], [ 132.557212, -11.603012 ], [ 131.824698,
-11.273782 ], [ 132.357224, -11.128519 ], [ 133.019561, -11.376411 ], [ 133.550846, -11.786515 ], [ 134.393068, -12.042365 ], [ 134.678632,
-11.941183 ], [ 135.298491, -12.248606 ], [ 135.882693, -11.962267 ], [ 136.258381, -12.049342 ], [ 136.492475, -11.857209 ], [ 136.951620,
-12.351959 ], [ 136.685125, -12.887223 ], [ 136.305407, -13.291230 ], [ 135.961758, -13.324509 ], [ 136.077617, -13.724278 ], [ 135.783836,
-14.223989 ], [ 135.428664, -14.715432 ], [ 135.500184, -14.997741 ], [ 136.295175, -15.550265 ], [ 137.065360, -15.870762 ], [ 137.580471,
-16.215082 ], [ 138.303217, -16.807604 ], [ 138.585164, -16.806622 ], [ 139.108543, -17.062679 ], [ 139.260575, -17.371601 ], [ 140.215245,
-17.710805 ], [ 140.875463, -17.369069 ], [ 141.071110, -16.832047 ], [ 141.274095, -16.388870 ], [ 141.398222, -15.840532 ], [ 141.702183,
-15.044921 ], [ 141.563380, -14.561333 ], [ 141.635520, -14.270395 ], [ 141.519869, -13.698078 ], [ 141.650920, -12.944688 ], [ 141.842691,
-12.741548 ], [ 141.686990, -12.407614 ], [ 141.928629, -11.877466 ], [ 142.118488, -11.328042 ], [ 142.143706, -11.042737 ], [ 142.515260,
-10.668186 ], [ 142.797310, -11.157355 ], [ 142.866763, -11.784707 ], [ 143.115947, -11.905630 ], [ 143.158632, -12.325656 ], [ 143.522124,
-12.834358 ], [ 143.597158, -13.400422 ], [ 143.561811, -13.763656 ] ] ] ] } }
                ]       };
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object

Comment: I need to use trail and error method to set parallels and rotate angle  for australia map. Is there a better way to use albers projection for any country?

Comment: Using another projection (e.g. Mercator) may be easier.