# Better way to scale/translate Map in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a newcomer to D3 and am trying to create my first map visualisation.

My map can be found here [San Francisco](http://pastebin.com/gAhuv10v)

My code can be seen here [Code](http://pastebin.com/9yYdx5KD)

I am sure there is a better way to scale and center this map than the trial and error method that I used as can be seen from the code. Could you suggest a better way of doing this ?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) answer might help

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. I could mark that as correct if you make that a separate answer.