# Get bounding box / extent of visible map tiles in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg, coordinates, bounding-box, extent

Let's say I have a standard tiled map like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797

How can I get the bounding box coordinates of the visible map?

In other words, how can I say exactly the extent of the map shown at any given time. I understand this as a bounding box but also as an extent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find answers to similar but specific questions but am leaving this up in case someone is searching for the general case.

From Elijah Meeks's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831103/d3-world-map-calculate-geo-bounds-on-zoom):

> To find the bounding box of the visual area of your map on screen,
>   simply use the `projection.invert()` function and feed it the top-left
>   and bottom-right corners of your SVG. If you have a 500x500 SVG, then
>   that looks like this:
>
> `projection.invert([0,0])`  `projection.invert([500,500])` This is a
>   bounding box of your screen, in lat-long (or whatever coordinate
>   system you're using).
>
> After that, you can get the bounds of your features and test to see if
>   they are fully-contained or intersecting or have their centroid within
>   those bounds. I'm not going to explain how to do that here, because
>   that's a different question with many different answers depending on
>   which definition of "within these bounds" you decide on.

So, plug in the `width` and `height`of the visible area into the projection generator. Voila, you have the box.