# D3.js map with HTML5 canvas not showing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to understand how to create a minimalistic example of a country map using d3.js and HTML5 **canvas**. I managed to implement the following code,

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// drawing a map in a canvas 
    var width = 960, height = 500; 
    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("height",height); 

    var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d"); 

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator();


    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection)
        .context(context);


    d3.json("tunisia.json", function(error, topology) {


     canvas
      .datum(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.governorates))
     .transition(); 

    });

</script>
</html>
```

But, no results have shown in the browser and no error received in the console, could you please check. Also, is there any minimalistic example of US map with canvas in d3.js

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://geoexamples.blogspot.ie/2013/02/mapping-with-d3js-canvas-or-svg.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: thanks for replying, I actually've seen that tutorial, but there is no explanation of the process of implementation. What I don't understand in particular is the definition of the projection (why mercator is not working for instance) and the configuration of type.

Comment: There's also [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3783604), which is simpler.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks, that's much clearer. Is there a full doc on d3.js operations related to canvas?

Comment: There's the [API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference).

Comment: yes but no specific part on canvas?, please also add your answer so I could accept it, thankx

Comment: I also tried to implement the simple example you gave on another map, http://bl.ocks.org/mohamed-ali/ab4cfd4947e3176b2902 but I am still having the same issue of not seeing errors or having the map rendered

Comment: You may simply not be able to see the map on your canvas. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: that's simply it!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't drawing anything inside the canvas, that's why it fails.

[image]

The following code will work and will give the result in the image, and you can play with it at [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kijiyu/1/):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// drawing a map in a canvas 
    var width = 960, height = 500; 
    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("height",height); 

    var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d"); 

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator();


    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection)
        .context(context);


    d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/8a7f176072d508218e120773943b595c998991be/world-50m.json", function(error, data) {
      var land = topojson.object(data, data.objects.land);


      context.strokeStyle = '#000000';  

      context.fillStyle = '#aaaaaa';  

      context.beginPath();
      path(land);
      context.fill();

    });

</script>
</html>
```

Let's see how does it work:

- The only part that changes is after loading the json
- I've changed your Tunisia.json file for another one, since I don't have your file. If it's a correct JSON, your file should work, although you'll see Tunisia quite small. To change this, change the scale property at the projection object.
- The variable land has all the polygons from the topojson file
- context is the object that used to draw elements in the canvas. It has many functions, to draw lines, erase, etc. [You have all theme here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-2dcontext-20100304/).
- Then we set the line color to black and the fill color to a grey using strokeStyle and fillStyle. When you call any function from this point, those values will be used
- Now a path is initiated with the method beginPath(), so all the following operations will add properties to this path
- The next order actually draws everything:

  - You added the context to the path definition, so all the data you pass to this path will be added to the context. Since the land variable has polygons, the polygons will be drawn.
- the fill method fills the polygons with the defined color. If you don't call it, nothing will be drawn