# How to automatically get the scale for a d3.geo.mercator projection with the topojson's bbox?

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have a topojson file created with the `--bbox` flag, I figured out how to get the center (where `b` is the bbox):

```
var center = [(b[0] + b[2]) / 2, (b[1] + b[3]) / 2]
```

Then I calculated the scale, the problem is that I calculated it for a equirectangular projection (because it's easy enough):

```
var wScale = width  / (Math.abs(b[0] - b[2]) / 360) / 2 / Math.PI
var hScale = height / (Math.abs(b[1] - b[3]) / 360) / 2 / Math.PI
var scale = Math.min(wScale, hScale)
```

[image: equirectangular straya]

I can't find a way to calculate it for a mercator projection.
I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) and tried to use the projection to get the scale and directly set the new scale:

```
projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .center(center)
    .scale(1)

[b0, b1] = projection([b[0], b[1]])
[b2, b3] = projection([b[2], b[3]])
scale = 1 / Math.max(Math.abs(b2 - b0) / width, Math.abs(b3 - b1) / height)

projection.scale(s)
```

But the result isn't perfect (poor Tasmania):

[image: sad mercator straya]

EDIT: Should I have post in https://gis.stackexchange.com/ or here is fine ?

Comment: Have you tried getting the bounds directly from the projection as in the answer you've linked to?

Comment: I did but the problem is that `path.bounds` doesn't return coordinates, and I can't do it on a g, it has to be path (and I have hundreds of path with real data, not in this tiny example).

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141812/