# D3.geo : responsive frame given a geojson object?

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I use Mike Bostock's code to [Center a map in d3 given a geoJSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691788/1974961).

The important part of the code is this:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("/d/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
  var states = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states),
      state = states.features.filter(function(d) { return d.id === 34; })[0];

/* ******************* AUTOCENTERING ************************* */
// Create a unit projection.
var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .scale(1)
    .translate([0, 0]);

// Create a path generator.
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

// Compute the bounds of a feature of interest, then derive scale & translate.
var b = path.bounds(state),
    s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
    t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

// Update the projection to use computed scale & translate.
projection
    .scale(s)
    .translate(t);
/* ******************* END *********************************** */

// Landmass
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(states)
      .attr("class", "feature")
      .attr("d", path);

// Focus 
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(state)
      .attr("class", "outline")
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

For example, [bl.ocks.org/4707858](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858)  zoom in such:

[image: project to bounding box]

**How to center and zoom on the target topo/geo.json AND adjust the svg frame dimensions so it fit a 5% margin on each size ?**

Comment: That's just taking the computed dimensions and adding 5%, or am I missing something?

Comment: Lars, your's right, I'am just writing it down (answer coming!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Mike's explained

Basically, Mike's code states the frame dimensions via

```
var width = 960, height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Once the frame is hardly set, then you check out the **largest limiting ratio** so your geojson shape fill your svg frame on its largest dimension relative to the svg frame dimensions widht & height. Aka, if the shape's width VS frame width or shape height VS frame height is the highest. This, in turn, help to recalculate the scale via `1/highest ratio` so the shape is as small as required. It's all done via:

```
var b = path.bounds(state),
    s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height);
// b as [[left, bottom], [right, top]]
// (b[1][0] - b[0][0]) = b.left - b.right = shape's width
// (b[1][3] - b[0][4]) = b.top - b.bottom = shape's height
```

Then, refreshing your scale and transition you get [Mike Bostock's zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858):

[image: project to bounding box]

#### New framing

To frame up around the geojson shape is actually a simplification of Mike's code. First, set temporary svg dimensions:

```
var width = 200;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width);
```

Then, get the dimensions of the shapes and compute around it :

```
var b = path.bounds(state);
    // b.s = b[0][1]; b.n = b[1][1]; b.w = b[0][0]; b.e = b[1][0];
    b.height = Math.abs(b[1][1] - b[0][1]); b.width = Math.abs(b[1][0] - b[0][0]);
var r = ( b.height / b.width );
var s = 0.9 / (b.width / width);                                // dimension of reference: `width` (constant)
//var s = 1 / Math.max(b.width / width, b.height / height );    // dimension of reference: largest side.
var t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (width*r - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2]; //translation
```

Refresh projection and svg's height:

```
 var proj = projection
      .scale(s)
      .translate(t);
  svg.attr("height", width*r);
```

It's done and **fit the pre-allocated `width=150px`, find the needed height, and zoom properly.** See http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/9643738d5f79c7b594d0

[image]
[image]
[image]