# D3.js zooming on specific path after loading finished

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, startup, topojson

I want to **triggle** an **event** on a path with **D3.js**. Here a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/kpL1uyy2/

So how can I say that a specific path is triggered by the zoomIntoArea function. I mean at the end I have some pathes and I want to load one specific at startup without clicking on it. I already tried:

```
zoomIntoArea(d3.select("lines"))
```

and some others but for sure that does not give me back the correct element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center a map in d3 given a geoJSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object)

Comment: No it is not. Because I already have a function to center. But I want to activate it after the loading finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the zoom behavior to explicitly zoom to a path, e.g.:

```
var bounds = path.bounds(d),
        dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
        dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
        x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
        y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
        scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
        translate = [
            width / 2 - scale * x, 
            height / 2 - scale * y];

svg.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 
        translate + ")scale(" + 
        scale + ")");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not what I was looking for. Well I need something in the d3.json ... that says center on the first path there. That needs to be triggered at the end or so. Or could you change the jsfiddle example with your code and show it to me. Maybe I just do not get your way? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, now I know where to put your code. Yeah that would be working indeed. But how can I can on using that function zoomIntoArea for that. I mean why again the same code. Thanks.

Comment: Alright now zoomIntoArea(featureCollection); is working. But I really have tested it that way before. Strange things happening here. Ok question is solved. Thank you.