# Zoom to arbitrary feature in D3 canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have taken an example of [Mike Bostock's D3 zoom transitions in canvas](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6242308). After trying to set the projection without magic numbers ([via this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object)) I'm still unable to zoom in on an arbitrary feature dynamically. I've created an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sd4frkm4/3/) that has a series of buttons at the bottom that correspond to geojson features.

It has a function called `onClick` that takes a feature. I'm trying to compute the translation and scale, and then update `zoomTo`, and finally call the `zoom transition` to ease into the bounding box.

```
function onClick(state) {
  console.log('zoom transition to state: ', state);

  var bounds = path.bounds(state),
      dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][4] - bounds[0][5],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][6] + bounds[1][7]) / 2,
      scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  console.log('bounds', bounds);
  console.log('scale', scale);
  console.log('translate', translate);

  // var locaction = getLocation(state);
  // var scale = getScale(state);

  // transition and zoom to state.
  // zoomTo(location, scale);
}
```

Other zooming examples like "Zoom to Bounding Box" don't quite fit in this case. Instead of rendering to SVG and using svg attributes like `transform`, we're rendering to canvas.  `path` is perfectly capable of rendering to HTML canvas, but take note that the `path` function is highly customized with its own projection. Indeed, attempting to use `bounds` to find the bounding box will give back NaN, NaN. These are logged to the console.

Success is being able to click on a state and watch it zoom in smoothly.

Comment: Seems like you want to do [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm striving for. However, I've hit a road block in my understanding of D3. Since we're writing to HTML canvas and using a very fast custom `path`, getting the bounds is tricky. I need a reliable way of getting the translate and scale for zooming - currently they give back NaN. I've edited my question above to reflect these challenges.

Comment: You should take a look at this upgraded version (d3.v4) https://bl.ocks.org/Fil/652458d1831e41de6efe1d453152131b

Answer (score 0):

I faced to the same problem and there is two solutions here:

- Zoom to centroid > https://bl.ocks.org/Fil/a8cfbbfd0100d38241beb48d23c9d4d1
- Zoom to bounding box > https://bl.ocks.org/lacroute/af1b46da4cb4579f93986b0119635ec2

The difficulty was to find a feature, then compute the bounds for finally update the zoom behavior.

The solution was to compute the bounds using `path.bounds` because we were using a backed projection in the topojson, then convert it in lat/lng with `projection.invert` to apply it to the zoom.

Hope it will help you.