# d3 world map positioning

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hey guys I am completely new to d3 however I feel like what I am trying to do is simple.

I am literally using the src code from this example
http://techslides.com/demos/d3/worldmap-template.html
BUT I just want to center above the pacific ocean(california would be slightly to right of middle of box)

I came up with this by just trial and error

```
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([600, 400])
    .center([-100, 5 ])
    .scale(300);
```

which looks like

[image: but I cant zoom out to view the whole original map, it just clips it to this area]

but I cant zoom out to view the whole original map, it just clips it to this area..

and lastly which is unrelated.. how can I color these countries in an efficient manner. I see in the json each country has its own color but I don't want to have to go in and manually change each one.

Thanks!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'll give this a shot(kind of going over my head haha)