# D3 mercator projection - how to scale and translate map of Sweden correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I'm getting into the mapping functionality of D3 javascript. I have created a json file that contains the map data for Sweden and drawn the map successfully. The issue is that I cannot get the map to scale to an appropriate size. I have played around with

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(7300).translate([0,1980]);
```

for a while now, adjusting the values for scale() and translate(), but I can't get it to behave the way I want.

I just want to blow up the map to a readable size.

The map can be viewed here is here: http://bl.ocks.org/sebarn/14dc2f287b682c44b8b5
The code is here: https://gist.github.com/sebarn/14dc2f287b682c44b8b5

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should have a look at this answer : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object

Comment: Thank you, @codename44. I'll check it out.