# D3 Geo Mapping Fitting Map to SVG Container

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am drawing a map in d3.js. I want my map to fill my svg container. It should be stretch or shrink as a function of the svg height and width.

```
    var width = 500;
    var height = 700;

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale((width + 1) / 2 / Math.PI)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
        .precision(.1);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("border", border);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    var g = svg.append("g");

    d3.json("world.json", function(error, topology) {
        g.selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.countries).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
    });
```

I think I am close with the projection I am defining. My translation function centers the map where I want it and my scale function resizes my map in terms of width. So that as svg width container changes size the map will stretch or shrink as needed. Ideally I would like to scale by x and scale by y (width, height). I saw in some other post that you can define a layer for the map (as I am doing now) but apply transforms on the layer. I would like to avoid this is possible and do all the work in the projection.

The svg container will is static it will not change sizes after it is created.

[Center a map in d3 given a geoJSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) does not answer my question because it computes the scale based on a feature. I need to know how to compute it based on the svg container.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object