# d3.js set TopoJSON map boundaries

Tags: d3.js, projection, topology

I have removed Antarctica from my TopoJSON file and now there's a big margin at the bottom of the d3 map:

[image]

http://www.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/d3-map-1.html

As a result, when zooming in and panning there's a huge blank space at the bottom. I've been trying for the past hour to fix this, but wasn't able to. I can't figure out if what needs changing is the TopoJSON file or if I can make this using the d3 projection and zoom behavior code.

HELP!

Comment: Use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) to fit the map to the screen.