# Scale/zoom D3 layer on Leaflet map to layer bounds

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to create a map with an added D3 layer on top. I want to automatically scale and zoom to the overlay layer, similar to the way you can automatically fit geo objects within their container in pure D3 ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691788/3856666)).

In making Leaflet and D3 play nicely I have to use a custom geo transformation per [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/):

```
function projectPoint(x, y) {
  var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
  this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
}

var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);
```

This makes projecting D3 onto a Leaflet map effortless, but I'm left without any clue as to how to determine latitude/longitude for my layer map. I need these coordinates in order to set the center, then I'd also need to set the zoom level.

How can I set automatically `setView` and `setZoom` in Leaflet to fit a D3 overlay layer?

Here is my implementation:

```
var map = new L.Map("map", {
    // Initialize map with arbitrary center/zoom
    center: [37.8, -96.9], 
    zoom: 4
})

var layer = map
    .addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"));

var figure = d3.select('figure');
var width = figure.node().clientWidth;
var height = figure.node().clientHeight;

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane)
    .append("svg")
    .style('width', width)
    .style('height', height);

var g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

function projectPoint(x, y) {
    var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
    this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
}

var transform = d3.geo.transform({ point: projectPoint });
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

d3.json('conway-ar.json', function(error, collection) {
    if (error) console.warn(error);

    var city = g.append('path')
        .datum(collection.city.geometry)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr('d', path);

    // Update center/zoom based on location of "city"
    // map.setView([someLat, someLng]);
    // map.setZoom(someZoomLevel);

    map.on('viewreset', update);
    update();

    function update() {
        city.attr('d', path);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to implement a solution using [Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay), a library for using D3 with Leaflet that automates the geo transforms.

First I recorded the bounds of the rendered path with `proj.pathFromGeojson.bounds(d)`. This library had a handy method that converted layer points to latitude/longitude, `proj.layerPointToLatLng`. I was then able to use D3's `map.fitBounds` to simultaneously adjust the center/zoom based on the recorded boundaries. See the following code:

```
var bounds = [];
var city = sel.append('path')
  .datum(cityGeo)
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    bounds = proj.pathFromGeojson.bounds(d);
    return proj.pathFromGeojson(d); 
  });

var b = [proj.layerPointToLatLng(bounds[0]),
         proj.layerPointToLatLng(bounds[1])];
map.fitBounds(b);
```

The full implementation of this can be seen in my [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/matt81m/47033dfacfd7553489ea).