# How to use d3 to display geojson file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization, geojson

I'm have a geojson file of the wards of Chicago and I'm trying to render it on the browser using d3. Here is the geojson [file](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Wards-2015-/sp34-6z76).

You click on export, then you'll see download geojson. Also here is the js script I have to render it. :

```
<script>
  var geoCanvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000)

  d3.json("wards-chi.geojson", function(data) {

    var group = geoCanvas.selectAll("g")
      .data(data.features)
      .enter()
      .append("g")

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(100000);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var areas = group.append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("fill", "steelblue");


  });
</script>
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYgme.png) is how it is rendered.

Whats rendered is nothing, at least nothing is visable or showing

I also used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJgEx_yb4u0) tutorial, pretty much verbatim.

Comment: You need to center your projection to your geojson.  See this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object).  I've applied it to your code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TKVg7QltzJyQiwT61Fhk?p=preview).

Comment: Awesome! thanks a bunch.