# D3 projection plots a very small SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a topoJSON data of San Francisco that I am plotting using `geoAlbers` projection. However, the resulting SVG is pretty small, like a tiny spec. I have used `scale` and `translate`. Either the svg stays the same, or it disappears from the page. I already checked out this link: [Center a map in d3 given a geoJSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object)
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
let width = 1050,
  height = 900;
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

d3.json('/sfmaps/sfarteriesTopo.json', (error, topology) => {
  const b = topology.bbox;
  const streets = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.arteries).features;
   var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();
  var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
  svg.selectAll('.streets')
          .data(streets)
          .enter().append('path')
          .attr('class', 'streets')
          .attr('d', path);

});
```

Here is what I have tried:

1. `projection.scale(700)`: shifts position of the tiny SVG, but size remains same.
2. `scale(700).translate([width/2, height/2])`: shifts position again and size is still the same.
3. `scale(2)`: SVG becomes smaller.

I am trying out d3 for the first time, so any pointers appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: could you create something runnable, i.e. something that doesn't depend on /sfmaps/sfarteriesTopo.json and is a stack snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was using a very small scale. To fix this, I used a scale of 16000 and it worked well. I calculated scale from the bounds of the geoJSON object.