# d3 json resulting in empty svg tag

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to plot data from a geojson file inside an svg using d3. But I am getting a blank image. Developer tools shows that the geojson file was loaded but the svg element is empty

```js
var svg = d3.select("#mainSvg");
        var projection = d3.geoMercator();
        var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
        d3.json("static/geojson/roads.geojson").then(function(geojson) {
            svg.selectAll("path")
               .data(geojson.features)
               .enter()
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", path)
               .style("fill", "steelblue");
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE : The solution mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365785/6162420 helped to solve this
I am not a D3 expert, but I tried few changes and it worked. Please verify the map rendered is accurate

It looks like the svg is rendering paths, but not fitting into it.
I made a few changes in your code.
Add `projection.fitSize([800,600],geojson);` to fit to the path

```js
var svg = d3.select("#mainSvg");
// Define projection and path
var projection = d3.geoMercator();
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

// Load GeoJSON data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/openlayers/main/examples/data/geojson/roads-seoul.geojson")
  .then(function(geojson) {
   projection.fitSize([800,600],geojson);
    // Render roads
    svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(geojson.features)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("d", path)
       .style("fill", "red");
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error("Error loading or processing GeoJSON data:", err);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="mainSvg" width="800" height="600"></svg>

    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, but, I had to change to v5 of the d3 javascript (otherwise the geojson displays incorrectly).