# Leaflet: pan map to new set of coordinates at new zoom-level on user action

Tags: leaflet, zooming, panning

I have a web app with a list of GPS-check-ins from field agents.

I would like to pan/zoom the current map/view when a check-in item from the list is clicked.

I have setup the leaflet map and click event like so:

```
function checkin_clicked(dt, mobile, address, lat, lon) {
    console.log(dt, mobile, address, lat, lon);

    var html = '<div style="width: 300px;" class="message"><img class="message-avatar" src="media/profile-pics/{mobile}.jpg" alt="">    <a class="message-author" href="#"> {name} </a>    <span class="message-date"> {date} </span>    <span class="message-content">    {address}    </span></div>'

    html = html.replace("{address}", address);
    html = html.replace("{mobile}", mobile);
    html = html.replace("{date}", dt);
    html = html.replace("{name}", mobile);

    map.setView([lat, lon], 14);

    var popup = L.popup()
            .setLatLng([lat,lon])
            .setContent(html)
            .openOn(map);
}
```

function setup_map() {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([8.2, 6.95], 7);

```
L.tileLayer('http://localhost/tileserver/tiles.aspx?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}', {
    minZoom: 7, maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);
```

}

Please how do I perform this action.

I have seen this: [How to change the map center in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735303/how-to-change-the-map-center-in-leaflet) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735612/44080

But in my case I need to adjust the zoom level while panning.

**Edit**: I added map.setview in my click event, now i get this error:

```
 "Map container is already initialized"
```

Comment: This sounds like a task for [map.setView](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview).

Comment: @nathansnider will it not simply redraw the map?

Comment: Well, for instance, `map.setView([34.05, -118.25], 15)` will set the view on Los Angeles at zoom level 15. In your code, in your `checkin_clicked` function, you can move to the desired location at the maximum zoom level using `map.setView([lat, lon], 18)`. Is that what you want, or are you looking for something different?

Comment: @nathansnider thanks

Comment: @nathansnider i get this error: "Map container is already initialized"

Comment: @CharlesO you should remove `map = L.map('map');` from your `checkin_clicked` function. And declare `map` variable outside your `setup_map` function.

Comment: @ghybs It totally works. Thanks.